# How can I make a one-on-one dictionary from a dictionary with a different number of keys in tuples?

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I am relatively new to Python (itself, using 3.8) and stackoverflow.
I have searched google and here a lot but cannot find a clue.

I have a dictionary with a different number of keys in tuples. Values are always one string.
Here, I simplified the code. Actual dictionary has around 2000 keys.

```
{('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'): 'fruit', ( 'F', 'G', 'H'): 'veg', ('I', ): 'meet'}
```

This is what I want.

```
{'A': 'fruit', 'B': 'fruit', 'C': 'fruit', 'D': 'fruit', 'E': 'fruit', 'F': 'veg', 'G': 'veg', 'H': 'veg', 'I': 'meet'}
```

I tried to change the tuple into a list, repeat values up to len(i in tuple) and zip, etc. but I cannot combine keys and values one-on-one. Would you help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
d = {('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'): 'fruit', ( 'F', 'G', 'H'): 'veg', ('I', ): 'meet'}
```

Each key is a tuple. For each element in this tuple, we want one key in our result. The value will be the original value.

```
res = {elem: val 
       for key, val in d.items() 
       for elem in key}
```

[Try online](https://tio.run/##VYzLCsIwEEX3@Yq7mwSKG3cFF771M4RONdikJY2FIn57nKkrZ3HgPuYOc370cV1Kgw3elrZUgXaKveKgOJKrQW16@SzSgk7qnhWXJZr4rgFdhaoDc6aPMYlHXeWOQ43p1sHgd22f8OS5Wkwf0ax85jBa99fQP02lKWND8jFbmXSlfAE)

Comment: Glad to help! Since you're new here, please [accept the answers that best answers your question and upvote answers that help you (for all questions)](/help/someone-answers). Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: It seems I don't have enough points to vote yet. But once I have I will vote on it:)